# How to disable right click in Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-media-player

I have a WinForms app. In a form i have embeded Windows Media Player, but i don't want users to be able to right click in media player.

I have tried disabling ContextMenu for Media player but when i right click, i can still see the menu.

```
private void fMediaPlayer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player.URL = _url;
    Player.ContextMenu = null;
    Player.ContextMenuStrip = null;
}
```

PS: The menu i am talking about is default context menu whenever you right-click in Windows media player. Embeded to form or not.

Comment: A better attempt in my opinion would be to host a WPF MediaElement control which gives you much more flexibility and safety than MP activeX.

Answer (score 2):

Setting AxWindowsMediaPlayer.[enableContextMenu property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as false does the trick. Please verify if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the **context menu** using the following code:-

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.enableContextMenu = false;
```

The right click options will then not be available.

Answer (score 1):

in the MouseDown click event check which button was pressed and if it was the right button just return.

```
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        return;
    }
    else//left or middle click
    {
        //do something here
    }
```

Comment: In click event, first media player is showing the menu and than debugger is coming to click event.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the design time attribute doesn't work and you have to do it during run time.
Use this line of code in the onload

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer.enableContextMenu = false;
```

Worked for me.